# Meteor : Buisness Object

Tags: meteor

I started Meteor a few months ago.

I would like to know if using cursor.observeChanges for buisness objects is a good idea

I want to separate operations and views so I can uses the same operations in many views/events, and I want to know if it is a good idea.

Someone told me, we should not separate operations on mongo from view.

So my question is : Is it a good idea to to Buisness Objects with Meteor ?

Tanks for reading me.

Answer (score 2):

`cursor.observeChanges` is essentially what you get behind the scenes when you do normal `find()` queries and bind to template helpers due to its context being reactive.

In the meteor world, the traditional model/view/controller paradigm is shifted towards a reactive data-on-the-wire concept including features like latency compensation.

What you refer to as a business object is basically a representation of your business data which is strongly typed, has a type of its own, atomic, and has only one task of representing.

You can achieve that kind of separation of concerns in any language/framework, including meteor. That only depends on how you lay out, structure and abstract your code.

What Meteor brings into the equation is the toolset to build up an interface to your data with modern ux features that are otherwise very hard/expensive to get.

The only concern over business-class applications could be the fact that Meteor currently employs MongoDB by default. MongoDB has its own discussions around business applications whether they need transaction support, ad-hoc aggregation, foreign key relationships etc. But that is another topic.